# Value of combobox dynamically created in datagrid

Tags: c#, combobox, datagrid, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to convert bank account statements into another file format. The issue is that no bank delivers the same format of their statments and therefor I would like to create a more dynamic approach to make the understandable for my program.

So the idea is to read the statement into a datagrid and then by putting a combobox in the header of each column, from where I can select the data type present in the column. At this point I'm creating the headers dynamically on the event createautocolumn the comboboxes are populated by a list. So far so good.

But crucial is to be able to read the header combobox selected value. Here I'm unsuccessful. I can't seem to access the shown value like combobox1.text. While debugging I do notice the the combobox never sets the value of the databinding, just uses get.

Below is the code being used to dynamically create the comboboxes

```
public string ValueString {get; set;}

var dropDown = new ComboBox() { IsEditable =true, MinWidth = 100, ItemsSource = countries, SelectedValue = new Binding(ValueString) { Mode=BindingMode.Default, Path= new PropertyPath(ValueString) }, }

e.Column.Header = dropDown;
```

Yes, I'm a newbie and would really appriciate your input. What am I missing, why won't it set the selected value to the ValueString?

Comment: Instead of dynamic, why not add the ComboBox to Column header at design time?

Comment: Would that be poosible to do even though I need to use autogenerate columns = true?